# Looping through directories and files at the same time

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to copy values from few excel files into one. I am trying to achieve that by first looping through directories and then files. However, I get an error saying that the size of source cells doesn't equal to the target range.

```
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Range("b8:b9")
    MsgBox (cell)
    strfile = Dir$(cell & "\" & "*.xlsm", vbNormal)

    While strfile <> ""
        MsgBox (strfile)
        ' Open the file and get the source sheet
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(cell & "\" & strfile)
        Set inSource = wbSource.Sheets("OUTPUT_INSTRUMENT")
        Set enSource = wbSource.Sheets("OUTPUT_ENTITY")
        Set prSource = wbSource.Sheets("OUTPUT_PROTECTION")

        'Copy the data
        Call CopyHeaders(inSource, inTarget, enSource, enTarget, prSource, prTarget)
        Call CopyData(inSource, inTarget, enSource, enTarget, prSource, prTarget)

        'Close the workbook and move to the next file.
        wbSource.Close False
        strfile = Dir$()
    Wend
Next cell
```

Those are the values in B8:B9

```
C:\Users\gdsg\Desktop\One
C:\Users\gdsg\Desktop\Two
```

Each of these folders has multiple files and we first check for those two directories and then for all the files with `DIR()`. Perhaps a way out would be to replace the `While` loop with a `For each`?

---

Please find the additional definitions below. Source sheets are looped through the directory.

```
Set inTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instrument")
Set enTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Entity")
Set prTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Protection")

 Sub CopyData(ByRef inSource As Worksheet, inTarget As Worksheet, enSource As Worksheet, enTarget As Worksheet, prSource As Worksheet, prTarget As Worksheet)

inSource.Range("5" & ":" & inSource.Rows.Count).Copy
inTarget.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

enSource.Range("5" & ":" & enSource.Rows.Count).Copy
enTarget.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

prSource.Range("5" & ":" & prSource.Rows.Count).Copy
prTarget.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you define `inTarget`, `prSource` and `prTarget`?

Comment: I'm afraid we need to see `CopyHeaders()` and `CopyData()` codes, too...

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: error is thrown by inTarget.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Of..... But everything works if I have only one file in the directory. In my opinion I should change both nested loops to For Each or to While

Comment: what's the value of `inSource.Rows.Count` when it errors out?

Comment: You are copying date from `inSource` to `inTarget`. When this happens, `ThisWorkbook` has changed. Try resetting your `Target` sheets again after `CopyData` call

Comment: The value is 1048576, because I am taking everything. But i think the issues is with the target sheet.. It says paste special of range class failed. @Zac How do i that? I think it should be done automatically by the loop, that's why i think the problem is there.

Comment: Are all of the files Excel 2007+?  If you have an Excel 2003 file, then it will only have 65536 rows, so an unqualified `Rows.Count` pulling 1048576 from the Worksheet *running* the macro will cause an error.  Assuming that `inTarget` is the Worksheet you are copying from, try `inTarget.Cells(inTarget.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)` so that you take the Max number of Rows from the sheet you are acting on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you're attempting to paste more rows then you can

with

```
inSource.Range("5" & ":" & inSource.Rows.Count).Copy
```

you're copying ALL source sheet rows but the first five ones, while with

```
inTarget.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

you're pasting them in target sheet starting from the row after last not empty value in column A

but should this latter index be greater then 5 then your target sheet has no room for all those rows

so you have to copy the exact amount of rows you actually need

you may then consider this helper sub

```
Sub CopySingleSheetData(sourceSheet As Worksheet, targetSht As Worksheet)
    With sourceSheet
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows(5).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count)).Copy
    End With
    targetSht.Range("A" & targetSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
End Sub
```

which you can call from your `CopyData()` sub, as follows

```
Sub CopyData(ByRef inSource As Worksheet, inTarget As Worksheet, enSource As Worksheet, enTarget As Worksheet, prSource As Worksheet, prTarget As Worksheet)
    CopySingleSheetData inSource, inTarget        
    CopySingleSheetData enSource, enTarget        
    CopySingleSheetData prSource, prTarget        
End Sub
```

Comment: This has been very helpful. I am however trying to add additional column, named directory (strfile) which I have now popping up as a message. I am trying with the code below (for CopySingleSheetData), but it doesn't work: 
targetSht.Range(targetSht.Columns.Count & targetSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strfile

Comment: what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: After copying headers add additional column called folder name, which I did. And then with CopySingleSheetData copy all the rows from each file, but at end of each row state the folder/file from which it's coming from.

Comment: well, that's quite a different matter from the original question. You'd better post a new question along with your code attempts and issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280523/vba-pasting-file-name-at-the-end-of-each-row

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to consolidate multiple Excel to one,

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As    Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("\\C:target folder here\")          
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next 
End Sub
```

It will work